# .NET windows forms win32 threads count

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms

When I debug my application, I see that sometimes there are a lot of running win32 threads. I made some tests, and realized that new win32 thread and be created even when I simply create control and add it to another.

25 win32 threads after UI setup, and 13 after some idle time.

Cannot say that this is an issue, I am simply wondering, why there are so many of them.

Comment: Prob. debugger threads.

Comment: Martin, on release configuration without debugger task manager shows +/- 3 threads, so it`s not that case.

Comment: Threads in the RPC threadpool, probably.  No idea why we have to guess at this when you can post a screenshot somewhere.  Disable unmanaged debugging so you don't have to worry about it.